# If I pocket my man and the queen in a single strike, is the queen covered?

Tags: carrom

Suppose there are 3 coins remaining on the board: one man of each colour and the queen. If, in a single strike, I pocket my man **followed by** the queen, have I covered the queen?

Answer (score 2):

If a player puts the queen and a carrom man of the player's own color in the pocket with one use of the striker, the queen is automatically covered, no matter which went first.

Copied from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrom#The_Queen)

Comment: This is correct. Note that if you didn't have a C/m pocketed yet (and thus didn't qualify to cover the Queen) then this would count as the qualifying C/m (no matter which went first, and you play on to try to cover. If in this situation you pocket 2 C/m and the Queen together then it covers it.